# Why is the resolution incorrectly set on boot after installing the Nvidia drivers?

Tags: boot, nvidia, grub2, plymouth

After installing the native Nvidia drivers on my Ubuntu 10.10, my boot screen resolution has been reset to 640x480 or so...

I tried to fix it by following these steps: http://idyllictux.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/lucidubuntu-10-04-high-resolution-plymouth-virtual-terminal-for-atinvidia-cards-with-proprietaryrestricted-driver/

Actually, the resolution is now 1440x900 but my splashscreen at boot is on the leftside..
I mean that logo with progressbar is on the middle left and not directly in the middle...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enabling Nvidia driver messes up splash screen](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen)

Answer (score 1):

There is easy top use script with very similar steps that solved my problem where procedure on your link couldn't. It also corrects the grub resolution as well so you may not wanna set the resolution too high. You can find it [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/script-to-fix-ubuntu-plymouth-for.html),