# Why does my system show blank screen during startup?

Tags: 10.10, drivers, nvidia, display

When I try to login to Ubuntu 10.10 I get a flickering screen for a second showing - 
Ubuntu 10.10
.............
and then I get a blank purple coloured screen[Ubuntu's theme colour] which doesn't progress any further

Can anybody suggest a remedy to this problem?

From whatever questions I searched in various Ubuntu Forums it seems like this problem is likely caused by a missing NVIDIA Display Driver[which is being used in my Sony Vaio Laptop] update in Ubuntu releases
If that's the case then how can I update my NVIDIA Display Driver for Ubuntu 10.10 without being able to log into the Ubuntu 10.10?

Answer (score 3):

You press `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F1` and install newest nvidia driver using the following line:

> sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

If you still can't login after restart, boot into recovery mode and run xfix:

[image]

login into machine, then go to drivers and activate the nvidia driver.

It's likely that you will have weird boot screen after using proprietary nvidia driver, you can repair it with [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9031/wrong-resolution-on-boot-after-installing-nvidia-drivers/9756#9756) solution.

good luck.

Comment: Thanks danizmax
I'll try out your solution coming weekend