# Can't fix Plymouth resolution by any means

Tags: 10.10, plymouth

Due to a bad update to 11.04 i had to completely reinstall Ubuntu, now i got everything pretty much the way it was before, except for plymouth.I've tried every script i found, every turorial i've found,

i've installed Plymouth Manager, i've installed a plymouth theme that worked before...and still, just plain white text, if it feels like showing me something, 'cause at times i don't even get to see the text mode, so, is there anything i can do witthout removing the ATI driver?, can i get rid of plymouth if it's not going to properly work?, are there an alternatives to plymouth?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enabling Nvidia driver messes up splash screen](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case you didn't find this tutorial, it worked for me:

http://kyleabaker.com/2010/07/11/how-to-fix-your-ubuntu-boot-screen/

Rather than fixing Plymouth, I believe this just uses framebuffer during boot with a user-chosen resolution.  It will give you more than text during boot, at least.

Comment: this script works it showed me what was missing, fxed it, and then it fixed the plymouth resolution, nice

Answer (score -1):

Uri,

Check out the link below it helped me when I was creating my own Ubuntu distro.

http://www.n00bsonubuntu.net/content/install-ubuntu-10-10-plymouth-theme-on-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat/

Comment: i tried this one too, it's actually the most known way to fix it, but didn't work, but thanks