# Install nvidia driver or not?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enabling Nvidia driver messes up splash screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen)
>   [Can't fix Plymouth resolution by any means](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24012/cant-fix-plymouth-resolution-by-any-means)

I've installed Ubuntu 11.10 recently and discovered the following problem: the default video driver works better than the proprietary Nvidia driver from www.nvidia.com. To be more specific: the Nvidia driver fails to show the correct resolution on the bootscreen, and there are some short delays when moving windows. I'm new to Linux, so is it me being dumb and doing something wrong, or is it just the drivers?

Comment: Plymouth (the boots plash) doesn't really work with the Nvidia driver unless you execute some workaround, the delays are because of Unity.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41135/slowdowns-while-using-firefox/41140#41140

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24012/cant-fix-plymouth-resolution-by-any-means