# Plymouth splash screen looks odd after switching to the Nvidia binary driver

Tags: 10.10, nvidia, plymouth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enabling Nvidia driver messes up splash screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen)

I am running Ubuntu 10.10, I switched to Nvidia drivers and this has messed up my boot splash screen. It looks like the resolution is off, it looks to be around 800x600 on boot (during the console stuff) and when switching to a virtual console (using <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F*</kbd>).

Any ideas how to fix this? Is this a issue with frame buffer resolution?