# Why is Ubuntu sticking with Plymouth despite the fact that it doesn't work with proprietary drivers?

Tags: plymouth, design

I know the background, just want to know why such decision by Canonical.

Comment: Ubuntu switched from Usplash to Plymouth because of various problems with Nvidia and ATI, but apparently, both don't work. Do you know of anything that does?

Comment: This is a question that is likely to start a discussion (as you can see from all the comments on @Jo-Erlend Schinstad answer) and there is not 1 single correct answer to this. I think you should start this over at ubuntuforums.org.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plymouth *does* work with the proprietary drivers - or at least it should.  You generally won't get the same native resolution bootsplash that you'll get with a kms driver, but the bootsplash should work.  You can even get a higher-resolution bootsplash with answers from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen).  We could conceivably detect that sort of thing by default, but it's fiddly and likely to break.

Regardless of the prettiness of the bootsplash, plymouth is necessary to multiplex the boot messages that happen in parallel during the event-based boot.

Comment: So it does have a reason besides the graphics...

Answer (score -1):

I haven't experienced any problems with it using proprietary drivers. But even if there are a few problems with very old VGAs from manufacturers who doesn't provide proper drivers for their hardware, that cannot hold everyone else back. We wouldn't accept a user interface that was designed for 320x200 just because that was once a common resolution, for instance. The show must go on. :)

Comment: Good for you, but the fact is, Plymouth doesn't work well with Nvidia and ATI. I always disable it.

Comment: That is not a fact if it works with my ATI card using proprietary drivers.

Comment: does it work out of the box? what distro version? Or you just don't know that you are using open source drivers?

Comment: It doesn't use proprietary drivers out of the box. But after installing them, at least I haven't noticed any problems. But it's been a while since I discovered that the open drivers are now better than the proprietary ones for Radeon HD5850, so I don't remember exactly what it looked like. The point would be the same in any case. If the drivers are bad, then that's a problem. But software must still evolve.