# After installing the proprietary NVIDIA driver, my boot splash is very large and stretched. Any fix?

Tags: boot, nvidia, plymouth

I know there have been solutions for previous versions of Ubuntu, but what is the best way to go about it now?

As an aside, if I have it disabled the splash is fine, but before the login manager shows there is a weird torn up flicker of sorts.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enabling Nvidia driver messes up splash screen](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen)

Answer (score 2):

Instructions for modifying:

/etc/default/grub
/etc/initramfs-tools/modules
/etc/grub.d/10_linux

As found on:  http://paolobernardi.wordpress.com/2011/05/01/fix-plymouth-on-ubuntu-after-installing-nvidia-or-ati-proprietary-drivers-for-ubuntu-11-04-natty/

This did the trick for me.  Paolo even includes a script to make it easy.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately.
Nvidia does not want to implement KMS in its drivers.
For the open source drivers(nouveau):
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1458230

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Imagine the linked site goes down for maintenance or forever - your answer would become worthless.