# Splash screen resolution is poor

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, resolution, plymouth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enabling Nvidia driver messes up splash screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen)

How come when I boot from CD or USB drive to install Ubuntu, the resolution of ubuntu splash screen is perfect, at full screen resolution of 1920x1080 - however, after installing the system along with the latest nvidia drivers, the logo looks nothing like when booting the live cd or live usb.

anyone know a fix to get 1080 for plymouth? (boot logo/splash)

Comment: thats just the side effect of using proprietary drivers.. you can sort of fix it with this http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/how-to-fix-the-plymouth-boot-screen-when-using-proprietary-graphics-drivers/

Comment: no support for 1080p resolution, surely by now it should have been fixed?

Comment: Blame nvidia/ati.  Same happens to me when using ATI drivers.  They don't support KMS

Comment: Make sure you read the many, very critical comments at the OMGUbuntu link before trying that 'solution'. Better just leave that splash screen alone.