# Plymouth boot screen not showing after enabling Nvidia drivers

Tags: 12.04, wubi, startup, plymouth

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with Wubi, When I first installed Ubuntu I could see the splash screen with the blinking dots, But after a couple of days it vanished (I've Nvidia drivers installed).

I searched around and found this
[Enabling Nvidia driver messes up splash screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen)

will it be safe to edit Grub as stated there(in Wubi installation)?, And will it work for 12.04?

Comment: Hare's another solution: [‘Fixing’ the Plymouth boot screen in Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/how-to-fix-the-plymouth-boot-screen-when-using-proprietary-graphics-drivers/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the same problem that I had but I found this solution which might help you.

[Purple start screen - no splash screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96616/purple-start-screen-no-splash-screen)

Comment: the file "splash" that opens from executing `gksu gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash` is empty, is that normal?

Comment: When I followed the instructions my file was also empty - so yes I think this is normal.