# Ubuntu won't load, freezes on purple screen

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, intel-graphics

Last time I restarted my computer, I could not get Ubuntu to load; the screen would either go black, or would hang at the purple screen indefinitely.  I have had some graphics problems in the past, but had put 'nomodeset' after 'quiet splash' in the grub command line, which at least let Ubuntu load.  That doesn't work now, and doesn't work if I remove it.

I looked up some answers, such as this one:
[Purple start screen - no splash screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96616/purple-start-screen-no-splash-screen)
However, when I enter the root in recovery mode in grub, I always get errors when I run those command lines and it won't let me modify the files.

Also, if I run in recovery mode and then choose 'resume normal boot', it will continue.  But instead of getting a usual interface, I get a black screen that asks for my username and password.  I enter these, and it tells me I'm in Ubuntu 12.04, but I'm still on a black screen with texts.  It also informs me that there are updates to install.  When I use the command 'sudo apt-get update', it starts to retrieve the information, but then the screen goes blank after a couple of seconds and I can't do anything anymore.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried booting from CD/DVD Media (different OS) just to make sure that it has nothing / something to do with your installation?

Comment: Yeah, when I try to boot from a live cd, I can't get any screen to load at all.

Comment: Okay, after forcing a reboot several times I got the live cd screen to load, but then if I took any action, the screen would go blank again.

Comment: Also, if I try to repair broken packages in recovery mode it says it cannot remove two files because they do not exist, and when trying to update in grub, it cannot retrieve all the updates.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the answer by going an alternate route, suggested here:
[How can I uninstall a graphics package in recover mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197978/how-can-i-uninstall-a-graphics-package-in-recover-mode/197983#197983)

Though I had to go a roundabout way to actually use the command, I was able to uninstall the last package I had updated, and my desktop loaded back up.