# How can I uninstall a graphics package in recover mode?

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics

So I've been having some graphics problems, and recently I installed these packages:
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-intel-82852855gm-drivers-in-ubuntu-using-ppa.html
But after installing those and restarting my computer, I cannot get Ubuntu to load--it freezes on the purple screen.  In recovery mode, I have tried to use root to fix some things, but it hasn't work, and I cannot connect to the internet in recovery mode to download anything else.

Is there any way I can uninstall these packages in recovery mode to revert back to what I had before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by loading the network drivers before dropping to the root shell, then reverse the installation of the Intel module:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Do you in fact have an Intel video card?  Which one.  You can get some information on it from

```
lshw -C display
```

if you are not root when you try to do this you will need to prefix it with sudo

Comment: The network drivers are already installed; they simply are not loaded.

Comment: Yah, umm that's what I meant :/

Comment: I do have an Intel card.  The info from that command is:  VGA compatible controller, 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller, pci@0000:00:02.0, version 09, 64bits, 33MHz, msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list, latency=0.  And when I try to load the network drivers through the recovery menu, a bunch of text will flash by, but then it stops at some point and won't go back to the menu.  Do I have to have an ethernet connection for this to work?  Also, I am using a DVI cord to connect to my monitor.  Could this also be causing problems?  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: So, I was able to get it to 'Resume Normal Boot' in Recovery Mode.  No graphics were available, but I could connect to the internet, so I was able to remove that package, and my desktop loaded.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

On the recovery mode menu, there should be an option to load network drivers:

[image]

Select that option, and confirm the request to remount the root filesystem in read-write mode. After some status text flashed by, you should arrive at the menu again, but with network drivers loaded. From there, select the option `root` to "drop to [a] root shell prompt."

You can then use `sudo apt-get remove` to remove the packages in question.

Also refer to fabricator4's answer to get info on what packages should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to find a work around.

First select dpkg on recovery menu, then select root and execute `dhclient eth0` to load the network drivers. From here you can execute `sudo apt-get remove purge nvidia-*` to nuke everything Nvidia from the system so we can start again with-out a re-install!