# Low resolution on "shut down" screen

Tags: 12.04, dell, resolution, shutdown

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 and everything runs fine and the resolution is correct when I am at the desktop etc. however the purple screen that appear when you shut down  with the dots ticking is in low resolution (probably 800x600) or something. Is this correct behaviour or do I need to fix something?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after I installed the nvidia drivers. The fix I used was the top answer:

[Enabling Nvidia driver messes up splash screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen)