# Im trying to change my screen resolution during boot

Tags: 17.10, vmware-fusion

I tried this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127851/change-boot-screen-resolution). It worked for the first reboot, but didnt stick for successive reboots. Any idea? I can change the resolution on user login, but i want to try the boot way. This is an Ubuntu 17.10 running as a VM in Vmware Fusion Pro 10

Answer (score 0):

About the procedure in the article you are referring to.

1. You have probably changed the config file but that is not enough. Double-check you executed update-grub afterwards (this makes the change permanent).

   `sudo update-grub`
2. You run it in a VM. Please check which video card you are emulating in that VM. In my case I chose video=QXL (but that is a VM created with QEMU-KVM; yours is probably different). Choose something more advanced than video=VGA or =Cirrus; for example chose VMVGA if that is available for your VM.

Comment: yeah i did sudo update-grub. I'll check your 2nd point and let you know

Comment: I don't have an option to decide what kind of video card I am emulating. I can just say how much graphic memory i can share. I have a radeon card on my macbook pro

Comment: Too bad you cannot change the virtual video card type in VMWare.

Comment: yeah that's sad.