# No splash screen after Nvidia propietary drivers

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, plymouth

After installing nvidia propietary drivers, splash screen shows nothing but a thick bar on top of screen and everything black. It is the same color that splash screen is.

[Enabling Nvidia driver messes up splash screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen) didn't work at all. After applying solution mentioned, now shows completely black screen. I'm using 12.04. I set the resolution to 1024x768 which is native and tried other resolutions as well with no results.

Comment: The link doesn't work, does anyone have an updated link?
[ubuntuone.com/0O5tJQPGQa36zKkq1Utlqw ](http://ubuntuone.com/0O5tJQPGQa36zKkq1Utlqw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also remove \$vt_handoff on line 70 in /etc/grub.d/10_linux and things should be working again.
If you're using the script it needs to be updated to work with the recent changes in this file.

Comment: It didn't worked. I'm not using the script. Should I restore that line?

Comment: try this script, it's the one from the answer you posted but i  modified it for 12.04, it should fix things for you, it works here at least :D http://ubuntuone.com/0O5tJQPGQa36zKkq1Utlqw

Comment: I worked! Letters on grub look a little blurry but I finally get a nice splash screen. Thank you.

Comment: is there any special modifications to the script so it works with ubuntu 13.04?
Is there anywhere where what the script is doing is explained? I'd like to know why it happens, and how it got solved.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:
http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Fix-the-Big-and-Ugly-Plymouth-Logo-in-Ubuntu-10-04-140810.shtml

Here is a script for user kww above:
http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/script-to-fix-ubuntu-plymouth-for.html

I cant reply to him or send a PM. (Am I missing something??) hopefully he will get this message or someone can contact him and point back here.

Also of note, I'm a "new user" so I might not have comment reply capabilities.