# Gnome broken splash screen

Tags: gnome, boot, plymouth, 13.04

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 today with gnome(First Ubuntu 13.04, then `apt-get install gnome-shell`). After this my boot screen is broken, you can see this here:

[image: broken screen]

This happened at Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 12.10 after installing `gnome-shell`(For gnome 3 desktop environment), too, at shutdown and start.
How can I fix this?

Additional information about graphic card and driver:

> Name: GeForce GTX 560 Ti
>
> Driver: 310.44

Comment: Use a live cd and check the results of `ls -l /var` (or put them in the question). Check for symbolic links from /run to /var/run and /run/lock to /var/run/lock. By the way: 13.04 is beta software and installing gnome-shell might be bugged. If so we can not help you. If this also happend on 12.10 I would advice tagging it 12.10 and not 13.04.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem and found a working solution (for me). Original information from this blog: http://jechem.blogspot.be/2011/04/fix-plymouth-splash-screen-in-ubuntu-on.html

First install hwinfo by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install v86d hwinfo
```

After the installation run the following command and note down the highest resolution:

```
sudo hwinfo --framebuffer
```

For me this was **Mode 0x0361: 1280x800 (+5120), 24 bits**, next edit the following file:

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

This will open the GRUB config file, we now look for **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"** and change it with the following, change your resolution with mine and also add the color depth (for me 24 could be 16 or 32).

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1280x800-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap"
```

Then find the following line (uncomment if needed) and change your resolution again, note that you don't include the color depth:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x800
```

Save and exit, next edit the following file:

```
gksu gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
```

Scroll to the end of the file and add the following line, again add your resolution and the colordepth like you did before:

```
uvesafb mode_option=1280x800-24 mtrr=3 scroll=ywrap
```

Then in the terminal type the following commands and then reboot:

```
echo FRAMEBUFFER=y | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
sudo update-grub
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

For me this fixed the problem, I tried all the other suggestions and scripts, none of them worked but this does, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

@JackLock, most probably your problem is unrelated to gnome-shell. It's caused by installing NVIDIA proprietary drivers. Look up [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen?rq=1), for instance; there are plenty similar discussions on Ubuntu forums. There are all sorts of workarounds, but AFAIK the problem does not have a fix or solution.

Answer (score -1):

See: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/script-to-fix-ubuntu-plymouth-for.html

It's an old fix, but still relevant. Same problem in Mint 14

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This fix is an extremely bad idea. Even though it might work, for many it doesn't. It changes stuff in a bad way and is not easily reversible. Don't use!