# How can I adjust framebuffer or X screen relative position?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, virtual-console, framebuffer

A long time ago <del>in a galaxy far, far away</del> I had fixed boot screen using [this nice solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen). Since that time I have been looking for the way to move framebuffer in virtual console slightly to the right and down, relatively to X screen position (or vice-versa), because it is shown in wrong position, and part of symbols cannot be seen. I reproduced look and feel of this problem using Crop tool and `fbgrab` command:

[image: Console Screenshot]

The GRUB menu also hides it's left side behind the screen, but I don't know how to make screenshot there without VirtualBox (and I doubt this screenshot will be useful).
However, the main X screen shows itself on the correct place (as it seems to me), and my monitor (ACER AL1916) always autotunes to this position, even if virtual console is shown.

I looked in many sources including AskUbuntu, but have found only one solution: switch from VGA cable to DVI, which it is not acceptable, because my graphic card (NVIDIA 6150SE) has only VGA port onboard.

I also found that `fbset` command can adjust screen parameters but need help for getting how does it work. Here is the output of `sudo fbset` command:

```
mode "1280x1024-77"
    # D: 131.096 MHz, H: 80.328 kHz, V: 76.649 Hz
    geometry 1280 1024 1280 1024 32
    timings 7628 160 32 16 4 160 4
    rgba 8/16,8/8,8/0,8/24
endmode
```

UPD: during reporting non-affected bug found one line that says:

```
.proc.driver.nvidia.warnings.fbdev:
 Your system is not currently configured to drive a VGA console
 on the primary VGA device. The NVIDIA Linux graphics driver
 requires the use of a text-mode VGA console. Use of other console
 drivers including, but not limited to, vesafb, may result in
 corruption and stability problems, and is not supported.
```

So, does anyone know how to adjust position of Virtual Console or X screen relatively to each other?

Comment: This post is too old to be migrated. Please ask a new question on the other site.