# How to fix plymouth (splash screen) in all Ubuntu releases!

Tags: drivers, grub2, nvidia, plymouth, proprietary

How to fix black or broken plymouth (splash screen) after installation of nvidia proprietary drivers in Ubuntu (it happens usually in all Ubuntu releases)? It's no matter what version of nvidia drivers I install bug is always present.

Comment: Works OK but in my case, GeForce 7300 LE, I had to drop down the colour depth to 16 - ie. 1280x1024x16 instead of 1280x1024x24 as the latter gave a poor resolution on the plymouth screen.

Comment: Wonderful. It also works with Intel perfectly. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enabling Nvidia driver messes up splash screen](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen)

Comment: Nope, in topics provied by you are outdated informations or missing/not needed to install packages.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here is a solution to address the problem of no plymouth (splash screen) in Ubuntu after an nVidia proprietary driver installation. It doesn't matter what Ubuntu version you use, it should work anyway.

Open your terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install v86d
```

Then

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find this line

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

and change for this one (*of course choose your resolution*)

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1440x900
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

Note: You can try `GRUB_GFXMODE=1440x900x24`, but beware of specifying the color depth. You must specify a supported value. If does not work then rather delete it. More information in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/gfxmode.html).

Also note: older Nvidia graphics cards require the `GRUB_GFXMODE` property in the format `<width>x<height>-<depth>` (e.g. `1920x1200-24`, but not `1920x1200x24`).

Save file and type in terminal

```
echo FRAMEBUFFER=y | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo update-grub
```

It worked for me in all Ubuntu versions.
Give it a try :)

Comment: Is this still valid for AMD graphic cards?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have AMD graphic so you need a test by yourself.

Comment: Already tested it, it works :)

Comment: This solution only partially works for me on Ubuntu GNOME 15.04. I have a 1600x900 display, and an Nvidia Geforce GT 620. After following the steps here, the splash shows for a few seconds, then the screen goes black and only the animated dots show before the screen goes black again.

Comment: Can you add some explanation or a link to where you got this from?

Comment: @A. Dueppen This happens to me to (Ubuntu 15.10). Did you find the solution?

Comment: @janoChen The solution still only partially works but I'm fine with it. I've heard that it's an issue with my graphics card being low-end so not getting as much driver support.

Comment: it works for me. Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Comment: Also Worked for me on ubuntu cinnamon 16.04.1, I just usedGRUB_GFXMODE=1440x900
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep          and  echo FRAMEBUFFER=y | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo update-grub

Comment: I SHOULD SAY, by this solution also It fixed my monitor goes to power saving / out of range during loads.  INDEED THANK YOU :)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with Nvidia driver 375.39. This procedure did not work for me. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Not working with Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.2 with NVidia 381...

Comment: This solution worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04, nvidia-driver-418, 1080ti, 2560x1440. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

If the above solution does not work, check that the $vt_handoff is used in the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file

In the file, search the line beginning with :

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz ...
```

in the appropriate section of the boot menu (e.g. first occurrence of this line if you want to restore splash screen for the first grub menu boot option) and make sure that this line ends with

```
... quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

Here is the example in my case (commented line replaced by second line), replace the xxxx by the existing UUID of the boot partition :

```
#   linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=xxxx ro   nmi_watchdog=0
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=xxxx ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia proprietarty drivers doesn't support KMS, until recently. KMS is required for plymouth (splash screen) to work. It is a Nvidia problem (not ubuntu canonical). I would recommend leaving it like that (it doesn't  affect your daily usage) and wait for nvidia 364.12 or newer in the Ubuntu repository. With nvidia 364.12 plymouth works.

If you are impatient, you can use this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-364
```

Comment: this answer is intended for new ubuntu users

Comment: For some reason, I can not use GPU rendering with Blender (CUDA) as soon as this driver is installed.

Comment: Try a newer driver  nvidia-367

Comment: @ByteHamster if I am not mistaken You need to install this package `nvidia-cuda-dev` to use CUDA.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think the cuda package was installed. Anyway, I later switched to a completely different distro for other reasons (no Plymouth anymore). Thanks for your suggestion anyway!