# No GUI before login on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line, nvidia, gui

After I installed Ubuntu 14.04 as the only OS on my computer on nomodeset to install the Nvidia drivers for my video card. I installed it and all is working properly.

The only problem that I have is that when I turn on my compurter I only see command lines instead of the Ubuntu logo.

After that the login screen works in a proper way even with the GUI.

I only want to get the Ubuntu logo instead of the command lines.

PS: when I turn off my computer, the same thing is repeated.

Comment: maybe you can follow [this step][1] 


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/362722/how-to-fix-splash-screen-in-all-ubuntu-releases

Let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: Since Nvidia is involved see http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers/508255#508255

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/default folder there is grub file. Often settings in this file are used to alter boot options. In this case, particularly we're interested in this line : `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` . To boot into console mode , there hast to be `"text"` written after equals sign, and in case you want gui boot , it would be  `"quiet splash"` . To have ubuntu booting with startup messages displayed, it would be `"splash"`. It appears that in your case you need to change `splash` to `quiet splash`

I'm booting with GUI enabled. Here's how those lines in my grub file look like:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Look at this file , and see what it says. (You could use this command just to view `cat /etc/default/grub`). Before editing, make a backup copy of the file, `sudo cp grub grub.backup` . To edit, use this command `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`. You didn't specify how much you are familiar with command line in your original question, so just in case you're not, nano is a command line text editor. When you're done editing,  just press Ctrl+X, then Y, then enter. Run `sudo update-grub` . After that reboot, see what happens.

Sources: [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-do-i-disable-x-at-boot-time-so-that-the-system-boots-in-text-mode/79682#79682)  and [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248/how-can-i-show-or-hide-boot-messages-when-ubuntu-starts)  ; mainly for your question you should refer to the second one.

Please let me know if this helps. Also, other fellow ubuntu users, please post comments or suggested improvements to my answer

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used the command cat /etc/default/grub and see this:

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"

I think that the problem could be the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX where is placed "nomodeset" which I used to install Ubuntu. 

PS: I'm not pretty familiar with command line

Comment: Yes, try to change that line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""   ; just like in my example. So press Ctrl+Alt+T to open the command line, and then type 'sudo nano /etc/default/grub '. It will prompt you for your password, and after you enter it, you should see nano text editor open that grub file. Edit the line, and when done press Ctrl+X, it will ask if you wanna save, press Y, it will ask filename to save, so just press enter, and it should save and exit back to just command line. Then run sudo update-grub, it will run bunch of lines, and when done, restart the machine

Comment: Also, get familiar with command line little by little - it's very useful for having much deeper control of your machine. Many times you only can get something fixed through command line.

Comment: Sorry but I did what you told me about quiting "nomodeset" and just leave: "". That didn't resolve my problem and I keep seeing my screen just like this: http://www.comoinstalarlinux.com/wp-content/uploads/como-instalar-ubuntu-12.10-001.jpg. What else can I do?

Comment: Should I add something where "nomodeset" was placed?