# Fixing boot animation for 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, plymouth, ubuntu-gnome, animations

So I have a clean install of 14.04 lts, and I've installed my nvidia proprietary driver. The boot animation now is just white text on a pink screen and . . . . (4 dots), I don't know why this changed. I tried to remove and install ubuntu plymouth theme but didn't work. Also, I've changed my unity desktop for gnome shell 3.10, and the same happens, just a lot of fugly text over a grey screen.

How do I get a neat ubuntu gnome boot animation or ubuntu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix splash screen in all Ubuntu releases!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/362722/how-to-fix-splash-screen-in-all-ubuntu-releases)

Answer (score 5):

**I suggest reinstalling package called "plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo".** it's the default plymouth theme used in ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
```

**Then make sure you are choosing it.**

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

**Then you will choose one of the installed themes (choose ubuntu-logo):**

```
There are 4 choices for the alternative default.plymouth (providing /lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth).

  Selection    Path                                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /lib/plymouth/themes/numix/numix.plymouth                       100       auto mode
  1            /lib/plymouth/themes/numix/numix.plymouth                       100       manual mode
* 2            /lib/plymouth/themes/solar/solar.plymouth                       10        manual mode
  3            /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo-scale-2.plymouth   99        manual mode
  4            /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth           100       manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

**Then save changes**

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

**Reboot, and check if it was solved**

Comment: nope, didn't work :|

Comment: Make sure you don't have remnants of old kernels, as these can cause `update-initramfs -u` to fail while updating certain boot elements. If it gives you errors like "grep:  /boot/3.18.0 no such file or directory" then this is likely the cause. Removing old kernel artifacts fixed the issue for me.