# How to remove Shutdown Screen Text on closedown (14.04) - NVidia Geforce card

Tags: nvidia, shutdown, system

Just changed my dual-head graphics card to a NVidia Geforce 210 (MIS 210 brand) from a previous failed AMD. Upon shutting computer down (desktop 14.04) the process shows all the termination of mySQL, server etc text instead of the lovely looking previous shutdown Ubuntu graphics.  It looks messy, scrappy and I would like it to look more clean as it did before.

What so I need to do to clean it up?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting text screen at start up too? I think there's answer for your question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/362722/how-to-fix-splash-screen-in-all-ubuntu-releases)

Comment: Not at startup (although I get an old style (Ubuntu 14.04') text line. Only at shutting down, the text says things like 'mysql server stopping', 'clam shutting' etc (or of similar wording) and runs left to right across the whole of the screen working downwards in the colours of white and orange.

Comment: You know, I'm using nvidia card and drivers too and I have that text screen too, I don't want to disable it for now, because it can bring some useful information in some cases. If you really want to get rid of it, check out link I send you before, I used that method before and I think it disabled text screen on start up as well as on shut down.

Comment: @Jacajack during a normal shutdown with a typical splashscreen, you can always press F2 to switch to text mode and back to view the readout. You can also do this during startup.