# No shutdown splash screen on Ubuntu with new Nvidia card and D-sub monitor

Tags: nvidia, shutdown, plymouth

I use Nvidia driver 346 and 
I have followed the instructions of this link
[How to fix plymouth (splash screen) in all Ubuntu releases!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362722/how-to-fix-splash-screen-in-all-ubuntu-releases)
But I've only managed to show the boot splash screen but not the shutdown's as you can see in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/embed/nD9OVbnp28g).

I guess it's probably due to that there is no D-sub socket on the video card and I have to use the HDVI to D-sub adaptor which made Ubuntu unable to detect it.
Please help me with the issue. Thanks in advance.
This is what I did:

```
sudo apt-get install v86d
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768x32
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep    
echo FRAMEBUFFER=y | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo update-grub2
```

There is boot-up splash screen, but no shut-down splash.
How can I make shut-down splash work?

Config:

- Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit
- Motherboard Gigabyte G1-sniper H6
- CPU intel® Core™ i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz × 8
- Video Card Nvidia GeForce GTX 750 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 *without D-sub*
- DVI to D-sub adaptor
- Display LG E2242C LCD with only a D-sub socket

`grub.conf`:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"
# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
#Fix nvidia splash screen
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768x32
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Don't put (solved) next to your title, but instead click the grey **☑** under the "0" at the left of your answer which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install v86d
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Replace the matching content with:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1024x768-24, mtrr=3, scroll=ywrap"
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

Then:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
```

add this:

```
uvesafb mode_option=1024x768-24 mtrr=3 scroll=ywrap
```

backup your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` if it exists and execute:

```
echo FRAMEBUFFER=y | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo update-grub2
```

restore your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Comment: use `gksudo gedit ...`

Comment: @A.B.: I have X11-forwarding on...  I tend to forget that normal people have to use gksudo!  Thanks!  And next time: feel free to edit it yourself!  You *can* do that you know!  It'll give you extra reputation!  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby, extra reputation is nice. Thx.  :)