# Grub2 not updating

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, suspend, bootloader

I have an Nvida Quadro FX2700M and I was trying to fix suspend so I switched to the proprietary driver. I then followed the steps [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362722/how-to-fix-splash-screen-in-all-ubuntu-releases) and now when I try updating Grub2, I get the error: `/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: d#: not found`. 
I am able to boot into my computer, but am unable to update any settings during bootup, nor am I able to install or uninstall software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue...
The 1st line in  "/etc/default/grub"   Had a "d" before the "#" so it was interpreting it is a line and not a comment.