# Missing boot screen after installing nvidia drivers at Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia, graphics

After fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 I saw boot screen (Ubuntu logo with dots under). Next I installed binary (proprietary) nvidia drivers 340.96 from official packages. After this step I do not see boot screen.

[nvidia binary (proprietary) drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUlE4.png)

Interestingly, boot screen I do not see, but shutdown screen I see.

I tried add "nomodeset" parameter to Grub (according to some advice), but without success.

Can you help me? It is cosmetic bug..., but I want to see it.

Comment: What do you expect to see on your boot screen?

Comment: I expect this: [boot screen](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/ubuntu-boot-flash-screen.jpg)

Comment: You should add your picture to your question. Also at this point I get a `403 Forbidden` error...

Comment: If I click on the "boot screen" link then I see right picture. Nevertheless it is the standard Ubuntu boot screen (Ubuntu logo with dots under).

Comment: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/ubuntu-boot-flash-screen.jpg

Comment: I still get a 403 for your images. You may want to test when you are not logged in that website. I see the exact same problem with the NVidia driver. It is supposed to show me the NVidia logo (I boot in a console then do `startx`, I prefer) but I nearly never ever see it. I think that the initialization process is such that the video out does not make it until later, at which point the boot process is done. It's my take, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the solution: [How to fix plymouth (splash screen) in all Ubuntu releases!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362722/how-to-fix-plymouth-splash-screen-in-all-ubuntu-releases/)

I used this advice and after a small correction it works. I wrote my knowledge to the original answer.

Comment: This advice work me. I see plymouth at Ubuntu 16.04. Nevertheless, plymouth do not work correctly. I see:

1) BIOS information from laptop
2) Black screen
3) Working plymouth (logo, animated dots, purplish background)
4) Black screen
5) Only animated dots on black background without logo
6) Black screen
7) NVIDIA logo
8) Black screen
9) Login screen
10) Black screen
11) Login screen

During whole "boot phase" my screen blink and change resolutions like on a merry-go-round. I do not understand why Canonical has not repaired this bug. Because these troubles are there in every release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Same thing here. Blinking or not displaying linux mint 18 logo and password input field. Also I can't type disk encryption password because keyboard is not working. I can type password only when `nosplash`  is added to boot options in grub. I have `nvidia gtx660` card and `nvidia-367` driver with kernel `4.4.0-31-generic`. I've tried changing nvidia drivers, kernel versions, using your solution and some other solutions from internet. Nothing works. Do you have any other ideas?