# Splash screen missing after Burg installed

Tags: screen, plymouth, burg

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on dual boot with Windows and I'm using Burg instead of Grub. Dual boot works fine. The Burg's theme works fine too. But the splashscreen is missing during loading of Ubuntu, just got black screen. I have a Nvidia graphic card with a propriety driver.

Here is my burg.cfg

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="3"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_THEME="magic"
GRUB_FOLD="saved"
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="true"
GRUB_GFXMODE=1366x768
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1366x768-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap"
```

Apply with :

```
echo FRAMEBUFFER=y | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
sudo update-burg
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

In order to fix my issue alone, before ask, I followed the guides below but no success, the splashscreen is missing.

http://jechem.blogspot.fr/2011/04/fix-plymouth-splash-screen-in-ubuntu-on.html

[How to fix plymouth (splash screen) in all Ubuntu releases!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362722/how-to-fix-plymouth-splash-screen-in-all-ubuntu-releases)

So, please, could you help me to have splashscreen?

Comment: Please, could reply to my ask, I need help to have splah screen.