# How to get Plymouth working with LUKS encryption after NVIDIA driver installation?

Tags: nvidia, plymouth, luks

When I first set my computer up with LUKS encryption, during boot, right after Grub2, Plymouth takes over and you get a nice graphical screen with the prompt to enter the passphrase. And that screens remain until the Ubuntu desktop opens.

Once I installed the NVIDIA driver for my video card, that graphical screen is gone, and right after Grub2, there is a text screen for passphrase entry, then once decryption takes place, the NVIDIA logo comes up. And on shutdown/restart, it also dumps into a text screen.

I've seen some solutions on fixing Plymouth after an NVIDIA driver is installed, but not sure if that works with LUKS encryption, and I don't want to risk screwing things up and not being able to decrypt the partition.

This is for Xubuntu 14.04.4

Comment: I tried the fix presented here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/362722/how-to-fix-plymouth-splash-screen-in-all-ubuntu-releases    It did bring back the graphical screen, but the resolution was off even though I specified my laptop's resolution of 1600x900.    Also there was an error once the desktop was launched:  late resume failure [non-free: nvidia]    I reverted to the snapshot I took just before trying this.  Still looking for a working solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This worked: [How to fix plymouth (splash screen) in all Ubuntu releases!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362722/how-to-fix-plymouth-splash-screen-in-all-ubuntu-releases)

The mistake I made when I first tried it is not using the correct resolution. I used the native resolution of my monitor, 1600x1200. But apparently Grub and Plymouth can have a different max resolution than the monitor and video card.

Since hwinfo is not available on Ubuntu 14.04, I booted into Grub2, dropped to command line and ran vbeinfo. Max resolution listed was 1280x800x32.

So with that info, the solution is:

```
sudo apt-get install v86d
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find this line:

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

leave commented out and add:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x800x32 (use max resolution found using vbeinfo)
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

Save file, then in terminal:

```
echo FRAMEBUFFER=y | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo update-grub
```

This gave me the 'correct' looking resolution for Plymouth both at startup and shutdown. Everything looks like it did before installing the nvidia driver, apart from a brief flash of the nvidia logo between Plymouth and the desktop launching.

I think the 'late resume failure' error report is unrelated, as I did not encounter this error report this time around.