# I get gray screen before I get the desktop

Tags: screen

When I boot up I get the Xubuntu screen loading, then it goes to a gray screen, and finally shows the desktop. How do I get rid of the gray screen? I dont know if I have Unity, Gnome, XFCE.

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do about it.

Comment: If you have Nvidia graphics - http://askubuntu.com/questions/362722/how-to-fix-plymouth-splash-screen-in-all-ubuntu-releases