# Ubuntu 16.04 Plymouth doesn't show splash screen at startup!

Tags: boot, 16.04, themes, plymouth

Ok so I upgraded ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04, and now my plymouth themes doesn't show splash screen(  only black screen after grub) at startup but during shutdown or restarting it shows the splash screen.

I tried changing the theme to default splash screen, but still no luck.

Can anyone help?

Comment: if your card is Nvidia, try [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/362998/509181), it fixed my Plymouth

Comment: My card is intel inbuilt, I don't have dedicated graphics card. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Chaten thanks although my card is intel that solution worked for me! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 16.04, plymouth path was changed.

You need to edit the `/etc/alternatives/default.plymouth` file.

Under the script caption make sure the directory is exactly like this:

`ImageDir=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/YOUR_PLYMOUTH_NAME/`
`ScriptFile=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/YOUR_PLYMOUTH_NAME/YOUR_PLYMOUTH_NAME.script`

Comment: I have checked that ImageDir and ScriptFile is correctly defined.  I have tried out the various alternative too. However, a black splash screen is always shown. What is the cause and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As Chetan said, that solution was for nVidia graphics card but it works for intel's inbuilt grapghics cards aslo.
I will provide the link again - [Solution is here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362722/how-to-fix-plymouth-splash-screen-in-all-ubuntu-releases?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Thanks again chetan.

Comment: Can you mark your answer as solved please? Thanks.

Comment: Website says you need to wait for 20 more hours before accepting your own answer.