# "Possible missing firmware" message while fixing Plymouth splash screen

Tags: boot, intel-graphics, plymouth, firmware

So, after installing Ubuntu, I was having problems with the Plymouth splash screen- it was not showing up during booting, nor when I shut my PC down. Sometimes it did show, but very rarely and only for a sec!

Then I found [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/821634/ubuntu-16-04-plymouth-doesnt-show-splash-screen-at-startup) to a post who had similar problems; I myself have an Intel built-in graphics card, so followed the instructions given in that post[(this one)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362722/how-to-fix-plymouth-splash-screen-in-all-ubuntu-releases?noredirect=1&lq=1), and my problem has now been resolved...

But during the troubleshooting, I got some warning/error messages that shows something like this:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin for module i915
```

What's with this missing firmware? I got the same message for some other commands too while troubleshooting Plymouth...

If anyone could clarify why this message is showing up I would very much appreciate it...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: what version of Ubuntu ?   
the following may be of us; note: i've not used/tested it
https://gist.github.com/zas/205372c824decb8e121baec2f86e1415  or (found at first url) https://askubuntu.com/questions/832524/updated-kernel-to-4-8-now-missing-firmware-warnings/832528#832528

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an intel graphics card?

This message means that a kernel module (i915) need a firmware file, but it can't find it.

If you do not use the i915 module or your graphics card does not use this particular firmware, you can ignore the error.

Comment: You said **If you do not use the i915 module or your graphics card does not use this particular firmware, you can ignore the error.**

How can I know if I'm using the module or my graphics card is using the firmware?

Comment: what card do you have? If it was needed you'd get an error on boot

Comment: Here's my output of `inxi -Fx`:

[link](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25591063/)