# Installing custom boot up screen using Plymouth, thoughts?

Tags: boot, kde, themes, plymouth

I'm running Ubuntu KDE (22.04). Currently, Plymouth is using that as the boot up screen. I have a custom boot up screen I would like to use (it's the zip file from https://store.kde.org/p/1360336/).

After unzipping the above folder, I moved it into `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/`. The `.plymouth` file for the custom theme can be found inside of the directory I moved into `/themes`.

I went into /etc/alternatives as per this solution ([Ubuntu 16.04 Plymouth doesn't show splash screen at startup!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/821634/ubuntu-16-04-plymouth-doesnt-show-splash-screen-at-startup)), but this did nothing.

When I run `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` it doesn't show up as an option on the list

After restarting, it doesn't use the new custom theme, only the default one. Is there something I need to do to point it towards this custom theme?

Comment: You've not provided your actual release; but also appear to have failed to rebuild the initialramdisk (*initramfs*) thus why it hasn't shown up yet.