# Glitchy graphics on the load screen

Tags: 16.04, gnome, kernel

I updated my kernel, and the system seems to be working just fine. Everything is stable, I just get glitchy graphics when the system is loading.

The "loading" text glitches through the Gnome loading screen.

Should I be worried about it?

I'm using an NVidia gtx 980 with 370.23 drivers

Comment: Does it show a text-based Ubuntu loading screen on a black background?

Comment: yes exactly that. it shows that and the gnome screen at the same time, only glitching where the text is, but the system after boot works just fine
Edit: only shows about 5-10 lines and boots in to the log in screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments:

> **Me:** Does it show a text-based Ubuntu loading screen on a black
>   background?
>
> **You:** yes exactly that. it shows that and the gnome screen at the same
>   time, only glitching where the text is, but the system after boot
>   works just fine Edit: only shows about 5-10 lines and boots in to the
>   log in screen

Don't worry about it at all. That simply means that the kernel upgrade broke KMS, which was a feature only [very recently added](https://askubuntu.com/a/799657/518562) anyway. All that means is that the driver handoff for the boot screen isn't working properly.

**But, that has ZERO effect on anything after the system is booted. So you're fine.**

---

If you want to try to fix it, you can try following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362722/how-to-fix-plymouth-splash-screen-in-all-ubuntu-releases), but as always, no guarantees.