# grub2 not booting after changes to grub file

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Single OS boot. 
After implementing the instructions given in https://askubuntu.com/a/362998 to rectify Ubuntu logo appearance during grub boot loading, I find my system unable to boot. It is stalled in a purple screen after grub2 menu stage.

I have gone through the instructions of this [website](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux) to manually boot up from grub but nothing happens after I issued the boot command.

How do I get grub to correctly boot my system in grub?

How do I correct the /etc/default/grub file, example to return it to the original state and perform update-grub and update-initramfs at grub prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of questions in there.  I can address this one of them:

> How do I correct the /etc/default/grub file?

Boot into live USB

Mount the ubuntu partition drive
`sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`

Mount the virtual filesystems:

```
        sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
        sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc 
        sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

To ensure that only the grub utilities from the LiveCD get executed, mount /usr

```
       sudo mount --bind /usr /mnt/usr 
       sudo chroot /mnt
```

Make your changes to /etc/default/grub using nano

run the updater
`sudo update-grub`

Exit chroot : CTRL-D on keyboard.

Unmount virtual filesystems:

```
       sudo umount /mnt/dev 
       sudo umount /mnt/proc
       sudo umount /mnt/sys 
       sudo umount /mnt/usr
       sudo umount /mnt
```

`sudo reboot`

Source: Sadly can't remember where I found this, but it worked, so I copied it and saved it.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this procedure. It worked & I do recommend to others having similar needs. I found the typo in my grub file and corrected it. It's fantastic to learn the use of `mount --bind` and `chroot`. Gratitude.

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped!