# Chroot update-grub

Tags: grub2

I set up a Windows partition **after** installing XUbuntu, so now I have to reinstall grub, in order to have my boot menu.
I tried with the Live XUbuntu, but it complaints there is no /dev/ device or so.

Please, help.

Comment: See procedure here https://askubuntu.com/a/891812/243321  That is for `update-grub` If you really want to install grub, substitute that in the procedure

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Without details of what went wrong, no one can help.

Comment: You're right, sorry. By the way, I found the issue: Windows has made its own boot partition, I had to delete it with GParted and, with BootRepair disk I installed GRUB back.