# Install Ubuntu 20.04 with ancient PCI video card, how to make "safe graphics" persistent?

Tags: system-installation, video

I have a very old [PCI card with Nvidia GeForce 4 MX420 chip](https://www.iodata.jp/news/2002/09/ga-gf420pci.htm)(dated back in 2002), using it on a Gigabyte GA-970A-DS3 mainboard(AMD 970A chipset).

I tried to install Ubuntu Linux 20.04 on it, but facing a problem using that video card.

If I boot the Ubuntu installer by its default behavior, on some GUI installer phase, the screen is scrambled, shown below:

[image: Scrambled video output]

Later, I find that if I execute the "Install Ubuntu (safe graphics)" menu item, the GUI installer gives normal video output, then I can finish the install phase normally.

[image: "Install Ubuntu (safe graphics)" menu item]

So, I think "safe graphics" means using basic VGA driver on my video card. That's OK, totally acceptable.

However, once the formal(installed) Linux boots up, the screen scrambles again, and I think it the installer did NOT relay "safe graphics" trait to the formal Ubuntu instance.

Then, how can I fix that formal Ubuntu instance by telling it to use basic VGA driver all the time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have integrated graphics on CPU? I found my Intel chip video from 2014  was faster than an older nVidia card. https://www.videocardbenchmark.net/low_end_gpus.html

Comment: No integrated graphics on my FX8120 CPU, and the GA-970A-DS3 mainboard does not have any video output ports(DVI, HDMI etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `/etc/default/grub` to add nomodeset to this line, for example:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`

Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem. But the tricky part is, I have to temporarily use a modern video card so that I can gain access to the Linux console to type in those grub commands. The default Ubuntu does not apt install `openssh-server`, so I have to resort to the locale console. Maybe an alternative way?

Comment: Here is how to modify grub from a live usb https://askubuntu.com/a/891812/243321 Be sure to use the "try ubuntu safe graphics" choice from the live usb menu!