# Why does Plymouth end so early?

Tags: plymouth

I would like to see the Plymouth screen until the boot  process has been completed.
In my case the Plymouth screen disappears. After that I only see a dash which change color  until the desktop starts.
Is it posible to keep Plymouth running until the end?

Using Ununtu 16.04

Thanks in advance for your suggestions

best regards

Comment: Are you using proprietary video drivers?

Comment: Does the greeter resolution match the boot resolution? This sounds like the Dm changing screen modes (ie boot has ended ans desktop is starting)

Comment: possibly a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/362722/how-to-fix-plymouth-splash-screen-in-all-ubuntu-releases please report back if the answer in this question fixes your problem.

Comment: @mondjunge -- I think he is asking why there is a black screen between plymouth and his greeter showing. Not that he has no plymouth.

Comment: @ Pilot6 I am using proprietary video drivers (NVIDIA)

Comment: @modjunge I will try to follow 362722 and report what happens. Thanks

Comment: @ravery correct. Could be related, though. If would know the definite answer, I would give an answer, not a comment. ;)

Answer (score 0):

362722 Solves the question. After showing the Ubuntu logo with 5 points underneath, the system shows only the points with another background. This changes to a black screen. About 15 sec later I see the mouse. About 20 sec later the desktop screen appears. I am using a quite old laptop with a Intel duo 2.80 Ghz which explains partially the wait time
Thanks again