# 18.04: Low Resolution In Grub and Splash After Installing Nvidia Driver

Tags: grub2, nvidia, 18.04, display-resolution, plymouth

I was getting some lag with the nouveau driver when editing large image files, so I gave the nvidia driver a try. It fixed the lag, but I had a new problem.

When I use the nouveau driver, I get grub and the splash screen at what looks like my monitor's native 1920 x 1080 resolution. However, when I install the recommended version of nvidia-driver-390 (the recommended version for my Asus GT440 card based on ubuntu-drivers devices), the resolution of grub and the splash screen is only 1024 x 768. I tried the alternative 340 driver, and it gave me the same result.

If I uninstall ubuntu-driver-390, and use apt autoremove to get rid of the leftovers, when I reboot I still get the lower resolution for grub and the splash screen even with nouveau until I run:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
```

which removes the following:

- nvidia-compute-utils-390*
- nvidia-dkms-390*
- nvidia-kernel-common-390*
- nvidia-prime*
- nvidia-settings*

So something to do with those left-over packages is causing the low resolution.

If I boot into a grub command line and run videoinfo, it tells me that my "preferred" resolution is 1920 x 1080, but 1920 x 1080 is not listed as a supported resolution. In fact, none of the supported resolutions are 16:9.

Just to test, I tried the solution listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/362998/761600) using 1920 x 1080, but I got a "video mode not supported" message. Not a surprise based on the results of videoinfo, I guess.

Clearly, whatever driver is active with nouveau is able to display a higher resolution. I should mention that my UEFI BIOS doesn't display in 1920 x 1080, either.

Is there a way to get my native resolution for grub and the splash screen in 18.04 and still use the nvidia driver?

Comment: Try this and see if it helps. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096629/change-ubuntu-server-18-04-lts-bionic-console-screen-resolution

Comment: Also check this for nvidia GFXMODE. https://askubuntu.com/questions/362722/how-to-fix-plymouth-splash-screen-in-all-ubuntu-releases

Comment: I tried the first one before posting, and it did not work. The second one sort of works, but you have to use "videoinfo" instead of "vbeinfo". The reason I say "sort of" is that the native resolution of my monitor, which seems to work fine when the nouveau driver is installed, isn't supported according to videoinfo when the nvidia-driver-390 is installed. The closest I can get is 1280 x 1024, so it still looks inferior to the nouveau driver.

Comment: Actually, the system boots faster running nouveau, so I'm sticking with it.

Comment: I had good experience with nvidia-365 driver using HWE kernel on previous Ubuntu versions, may be worth to try.