# Ubuntu splash screen not showing at boot

Tags: boot, macbook, plymouth

When I boot my MBP 2010 15 inch i go to the purple screen to choose the OS to load (in my case windows, Mac, Ubuntu). When I click Ubuntu it goes to a terminal like screen and says some technical computer jargon. And then Ubuntu boots.But I thought there was supposed to be a cool Ubuntu loading screen that was animated. How do I get the normal Ubuntu loading screen to boot? and is it possible to make a custom loading screen for Ubuntu?

Comment: In some cases you might not see the animation, just the purple screen, because it would to take longer to load the neccessary components to display the animation than to just get the system booted. That's my experience, but resuming from S5/hibernation gives me the animation.

Comment: Thanks, I think i'll just not use it then if it makes it slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install v86d
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

search for-`GRUB_GFXMODE=`
below this you need to type: `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=yourresolutionhere`

```
echo FRAMEBUFFER=y | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
sudo update-grub2
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/a/6040/40581

Comment: I've got a problem. I've tried all this but when Ubuntu loads the booting screen is just black. im using UBuntu 13.10