# Huge splash screen

Tags: boot, nvidia, screen

Just did clean install of Ubuntu 16.04. Everything was good, but the screen kept flashing after booting to desktop. The default X.org X server was set. I have a Geforce 7025 / nforce 630a video card. So, I set it to NVIDIA legacy binary driver version 304.131, the only option available. Now my Ubuntu splash screen is HUGE. I don't want to Bork my install so, how to bring back the normal size of the splash screen? I've tried these repairs below, but no joy.

[Enabling Nvidia driver messes up splash screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen)
[How to fix plymouth (splash screen) in all Ubuntu releases!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362722/how-to-fix-plymouth-splash-screen-in-all-ubuntu-releases)

Answer (score 0):

two things

First,

fix grub resolution:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Now, locate the line

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

and change it to this:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x800 
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

Set to your screen default instead of 1280x800 (1360x740 for example).

Next,

add framebuffer:

```
echo "echo FRAMEBUFFER=y" | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
```

This is not a typo echo is supposed to be written twice just as it says.

finally, update grub and initramfs:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo update-grub
```

reboot for the changes to take effect

Comment: No Joy. I even changed the resolution to match settings in "sudo hwinfo --framebuffer" no change. Thank you for assisting.

Comment: Well I guess no solution. When I use the default X.org driver it flashes like mad and it's very disturbing. When I use the NVIDIA legacy binary driver version 304.131 driver, Ubuntu splash screen is HUGE. So, I guess I'm stuck with the huge splash screen until someone comes up with a solution. Thanks.